# Create or get environment for Hadoop practice

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have started reading about hadoop. I want to learn practicals as well. As hadoop is distributed environment and made to run on linux, I cannot practice it on my local machine which runs windows. Is there any cloud or virtual machines available on internet where I can set up entire environment by my own and start learning? It is also fine I can get pre-configured hadoop cluster but I will prefer to configure by my own.

Answer (score 3):

**Cloudera** ( cloudera.com) has some preconfigured one-node environments. It is only 3GB, but you find every BigData components, what you need.

http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms.html

**Oracle** has also a VM, free for development nad testing: Oracle BigData Lite

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bigdata-appliance/oracle-bigdatalite-2104726.html

and **Hortonworks** has also a preconfigured sandbox.

I prefer the Cloudera environment. Oracle is good, if yoou wish to test the Sqoop component.

Comment: Single node environment can also be configured at local machine. Is the any cluster available for practice.?

Comment: Then I prefer to use docker environment. Here is a sample for docker cluster: https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker

Comment: I dont have high configuration system (2GB RAM), so I think VM will not work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi Adil, try to use Docker Environments.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to learn something about Hadoop, so I bought a **Raspberry Pi**, installed Raspbian wheezy and Hadoop following [these instructions](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

It's very well explained how to set up a Single-Node Cluster. The Hadoop on a Raspberry Pi is not very fast, but in my opinion it's fast enough to learn the basics of Hadoop.

If you want to set up a **single-node cluster on your local machine**, I would prefer to use a distribution, as [user3341955](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3341955/user3341955) already mentioned. I took *Hortonworks* because there was a very simple setup-guide for [Virtualbox on Mac OS X](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/12/tutorial-installing-a-apache-hadoop-single-node-cluster-with-hortonworks-data-platform/).

And the setup-guide for [VMware Player on Windows](http://de.hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/InstallingHortonworksSandboxonWindowsUsingVMwarePlayerv2.pdf):

Have fun with Hadoop :)

Comment: "you get the full version for free" -> the Cloudera free distribution also includes everything

Comment: Ah okay i haven't noticed yet. I thougt there you get only free trial Versions. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a cloud-based environment to play around, I suggest the [Cloudera Live demo](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-live.html), which is really the [Hue demo](http://demo.gethue.com/). It's basically a real instance of Hue (which is the UI that non-admin users would use and see) in front of a real cluster that is open to the public. You can browse the file system, issues queries, etc.

If you want to explore in more than superficial detail, yes you should run your own toy cluster. If you like the Cloudera distro, note that Cloudera Manager is free and is the installer program as well that can turn up a cluster in the cloud, like on Amazon EC2, for you.